# Macro redefinition in C and C++

Tags: c++, c

I know that this code is valid both in C and C++:

```
#define FOO 0
#define FOO 0
```

**ISO/IEC 14882:2011**

> 16.3 Macro replacement [cpp.replace]
>
> 2 An identifier currently defined as an object-like macro may be
>   redefined by another #define preprocessing directive provided that the
>   second definition is an object-like macro definition and the two
>   replacement lists are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed.
>   Likewise, an identifier currently defined as a function-like macro may
>   be redefined by another #define preprocessing directive provided that
>   the second definition is a function-like macro definition that has the
>   same number and spelling of parameters, and the two replacement lists
>   are identical, otherwise the program is ill-formed.

But what about this code?

```
#define FOO 0
#define FOO FOO
```

Replacement lists are not identical at the start of preprocessing (only when the first replacement occurs).

Comment: This seems like a bad approach to me. Likely to cause confusion and possible errors by future developers.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood I don't want to use this in real code, just interesting moment

Answer (score 6):

This is not allowed in either C or C++. The replacement list must be identical. What you're talking about (after the first pass) is the result of processing the replacement list<sup>1</sup>, not the replacement list itself. Since the replacement list itself is not identical, the code is not allowed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or at least what the result would be if the preprocessor worked a particular way that happens to be different from how it actually does.

Comment: In other words, with the possible exception of spaces, the right-hand side must be the same sequence of tokens.